# multiple click on single button while opening from one fragment to another?

Tags: java, android

I have created an application which uses the fragment, I am opening a fragment on the click of the first fragment with custom animation, meanwhile the animation is going on I am able to click the button on the first fragment and it creates 2 fragments. how can I not click on my button while moving from one fragment to another, I just don't want double click of the same button.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try below

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            view.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    // on animation complete, enable it
    // button.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `myButton.setEnabled(false)` in your click callback function.

Comment: Your button will still be disabled if you ever come back to this fragment if it is pushed to the back stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could try set `android:clickable` in your XML layout to determine whether a button can be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the following method into your code and call it when needed.

```
public void myMethod(boolean isLoading){
    myButton.setEnabled(!isLoading);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {view.setEnabled(false);}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below kotlin snippet

```
view.setOnClickListener {
    val tag = "my_dialog"
    val oldFragment: Fragment? = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
    if(!(oldFragment?.isAdded == true)) {
         val myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance()
         myDialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, tag)
    }
}
```

In case a fragment(with the tag specified) is already added to the activity then this code prevents new fragment creation and adding it to the activity.